# Why the need for Binding in this context

Tags: c#, wpf

i am starting WPF, looking at [How do o: Getting started with Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/dd776537.aspx)

i am abit confused why the need for

```
<ListBox Name="ListBox1" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource CustomerSource}}" >
```

why cant i do

```
<ListBox Name="ListBox1" ItemsSource="{StaticResource CustomerSource}" >
```

how do i know when i need `Binding`. because on 1st thought, just like i use a static resource in Styles

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource someStyle}"
```

why not

```
<Button Style="{Binding Source={StaticResource someStyle}}"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This example **assigns** a value retrieved from the resources using the specified key to the Text property:

```
<TextBox Text="{StaticResource SomeText}" />
```

This examples **binds** the Text property to a property on an object retrieved from the resources using the specified key:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource SomeObject}, Path=SomeProperty}" />
```

The [Binding class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.aspx) is used for **data binding** that is a way to surface data retrieved from a data source on the GUI, allowing users to interact with it. Without data binding values are simply assigned to the controls on the UI.

Bindings add a layer of abstraction between the UI controls and the underlying data source associated with it, providing a bounce of services. Here are some of the most important ones:

- Automatic propagation of changes in the data between the UI and the data source in either or both directions
- Conversion/formatting of values
- Notification through events

**Related resources:**

- [Data Binding Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx)
- [Binding Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You could also set the DataContext on the parent control instead.
If the ListBox is contained in for example a StackPanel for example.

```
<StackPanel x:Name="parentControl" DatContext="{StaticResource CustomerSource}">
<ListBox x:Name="ListBox1" ItemSource="{Binding}">
...
</ListBox>
</StackPanel>
```